# React form handeling?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

When using forms or input tags in react I use `useState` for the value of the form.

```
const [value,setvalue]=useState("");
onInput(e)=>{setvalue(e.target.value)};
```

But with this each time the user fills the form the component gets rerendered. Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Share more of your code in a code block format so that others will be able to really help you.  The component and state logic.

Comment: Yes, with `react-hook-form` this is possible - check out this short [video](https://react-hook-form.com/#rendering) to see the difference between `react-hook-form` and your `useState` approach.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a form you can use `onSubmit`

```js
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <input type="text" name="input1" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and in `handleSubmit` function:

```js
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var input1 = event.currentTarget.input1.value;
        // Do the rest
      }
```